# Which of Stocks, Bonds, Real Estate, Bitcoin, Gold, are not subject to devaluation of money?

Tags: inflation, quantitative-easing

[Currency in circulation from year 2000 to 2020](https://www.federalreserve.gov/paymentsystems/coin_data.htm) appeared to have increased 3x.  And a cappuccino in California went from $1.75 to $4.40, a beef noodle from $3.50 to $11, and a house from $600k to $1.5 million. Salary seemed to moved from $60k to $180k as well. Total compensation from $100k to $300k.

So if somebody is holding cash, now the cash would have shrunk to 1/3 or 1/2 if a 2% interest can still make $100 become $148 in 20 years. That, together if I sell the house, it "appreciated by 0.9 million" and subtracting the $250k exemption, $650k of that may be subject to capital gain tax, state and federal.

Which of Stocks, Bonds, Real Estate, Bitcoin, Gold, are not subject to devaluation of money?  If it is bonds, holding it from year 2000 to 2020, since it is just some type of collectible debt, isn't it very similar to how cash would devaluate?  For stocks, it seems growth stock and dividend earning stocks might be different too: if the dividend earning stock is very much tied to cash, won't it devaluate too?

The graph:

[image]

Comment: Everything you buy with money is subject to devaluation of money. If money is worth less then your money will buy less stuff, no matter what the stuff is.

Comment: Also the graph is missing a legend.

Comment: _Currency in Circulation_ has very little to do with devaluation - reducing it simply leads to a shortage of bills in daily life. The question is still valid, though.

Comment: @Aganju somehow it matches the prices of things going up 3 times

Comment: If the graph really matched "the prices of things going up 3 times", then the value of `$5`, `$10`, `$20` and `$50` bills would have **also** tripled.  But... they didn't.  That's why the graph does not demonstrate what you think it demonstrates.

Comment: @RonJohn isn't it true that when  $100 is a big deal, then beef noodle is $3.50, and when $100 is really kind of like $33, then that beef noodle now costly 3x, at $11?

Comment: @nonopolarity But the prices of things haven’t gone up three times. You’ve cherry-picked a few of the worst examples. What’s happened to the price of 65” flat-screen TVs? The CPI tells us that US prices on average increased by 53.6% from Jan 2000 to Jan 2020 (though some experts think that’s overstated, because it doesn’t fully take account of improvements in quality like for those 65” flat screen TVs).

Comment: @nonopolarity , you are confusing _correlation_ with _causation_. Just because they move in sync, doesn’t imply the one causes the other.

Comment: @MikeScott and if I don't care about 65" TVs, but I really care about cappucinoss and "a beef noodle"?

Comment: my God - does anyone still have a flat screen that small?  > shudders <  there should be  a charity ....

Comment: No, Nono, you're wrong.   **Seriously mistaken.** If prices were rising that much, **and we still used lots of cash** then the number of `$20` bills would have exploded, because that's how you'd pay for stuff in the `$20` to `$80` range.  But it hasn't (because we pay for almost everything with plastic).

Comment: @MikeScott the price of a 65 inch TV is always "the" exception.  You know how a 40 inch Plasma TV could cost US$10,000 when it first came out, and down to $8000, and nowadays the LCD type to $800 or even $600.

Comment: @RonJohn if long time ago when the hamburger was 5 cent, true, we carry one $20 billion and it can buy 400 hamburgers, and we don't have to carry that many $20 bills.  It used to be I can take $200 cash and spend it in two weeks.  Nowadays if I use cash and take out $300, it could be gone in a week. So that's true, the number of $20 bills we need is exploding

Comment: "the number of $20 bills we need is exploding".  Look carefully at your graph.  The number of `$20` bills has **not** exploded over the past 20 years.

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of controversial claims buried in your question, but I'll just directly tackle the fundamental misunderstanding I see, in that you think stock investment is subject to inflation:

"For stocks, it seems growth stock and dividend earning stocks might be different too: if the dividend earning stock is very much tied to cash, won't it devaluate too?"

The stock market represents ownership of public companies. People buy and sell ownership of these companies based on (in theory) the ultimate value of all future cash flows that such ownership will provide. That means dividends and liquidation proceeds. Companies that pay no dividends [probably because they can use every scrap of cash to keep investing in the same business model] just have a growing balance sheet, and they will ultimately either be bought out [giving owners a cash payout or perhaps shares in the acquiring company]. In that sense, dividends are not 'income' in the economic sense, they are just shaving off accrued profits in and exchanging them into cash to be delivered to shareholders.

So yes, dividends are paid in cash, *but those cash payments are made at future dates in time*. The cash that will be paid by TSLA as a dividend in the future doesn't even exist yet; they still need to earn revenue to be able to generate excess profits to pay future dividends.

**In that way, any non-cash investment** (including things like money market funds, if interest earned is near inflation) **is basically unaffected by inflation of cash itself**, as long as it isn't the ultra-rare "hyperinflation" that must always be watched for by central banks. This is the fundamental flaw of asking for BTC to be a replacement of cash - the true long-term economic costs of inflation only really hold true if you have a stack of cash under your mattress, not if you spend your money or invest it.

And of course, I can't answer a question which lists bitcoin without adding that I do not believe it has any inherent value, and unlike fiat currency, it cannot pay a tax debt to the government, so its value is highly suspect [hence the massive volatility - called "deflation" when the price goes up, and humorously "inflation" when the price goes down].

Comment: gold and silver really has no intrinsic value too, if looked at this way, because a gold bar at home is not much use except maybe to lift up my computer monitor a few inches higher

Comment: @nonopolarity - there have been 100 million words written on the obvious arguments on both sides of things like "silver has no value", what the hell "value" means etc.  it is inconceivable that such base issues can be settled, offhand, on a mailing list.  it would be like asking on the physics list "Say, what's dark matter" and someone gave an offhand answer "quarks!" you know?

Answer (score 3):

Don't confuse the inflation of a currency with the change in a very specific cost of living. I highly doubt that real estate prices in, say, Wyoming have tripled in the last 10 years. And cappuccino prices may have to do more with supply and demand of that product than inflation. Salaries are also not only locationally-dependent, but industry-dependent. I doubt that school teachers have seen their salaries triple in the last 20 years, even in California.

According to [this site](https://www.in2013dollars.com/us/inflation/2000), $1 in 2000 had the buying power of about $1.50 today, or an annualized inflation of about 2% per year.

Certainly the cost of living in your area has increased more than that, but so too have salaries (again, on average, so some more than others). If your compensation tripled in the last 20 years, you're doing *much better* than inflation (5.6% per year vs 2% per year).

Most anything that returns money is subject to inflation of the currency. Even a fixed-rate bond is, since the future payments are fixed *in today's dollars*. Floating-rate bonds *might* do better if inflation is higher than expected, but it depends on how well inflation and the interest rated the bond is based on are linked. There are, however, inflation-linked bonds that return a variable amount linked to a CPI of some sort, but they are priced according to the *current expectation* of inflation, meaning you don't make a risk-free profit unless inflation is *higher* than expected.

Comment: I know, if a house in Chicago or Florida was $275k in 2000 and now $400k, it seems like the increase of only 50% is paradise

Comment: @nonopolarity - The Case-Shiller home price index for Chicago https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CHXRSA shows that home prices increased by a bit over 40% from Jan 2000 to Jan 2020.  I'm sure that there exists a house in Chicago that went from $275k to $400k but on average home prices grew slightly slower than inflation over the past 20 years.

Answer (score -4):

A simple answer:

> Which of Stocks, Bonds, Real Estate, Bitcoin, Gold, are not subject to devaluation of money?

All of these can plummet in dollar price, and often do, over (say) 10-50 year time spans.

It's **Just That Simple.**

> "Devaluation of money"

Nobody has a clue what this is.

Nobody has a clue what inflation is.

There are a couple of "measures of inflation" but that's just some body of academics who pick, out of the air, some numbers.  It means *literally nothing*.

There is no agreed, definitive, common or even logical meaning to the phrase "devaluation of money" and no agreement at all about it.

There have been a couple examples of hyperinflation, but academics use them randomly in wildly different ways to support completely different ideas.

> Books.

I suggest reading this unusual book

[https://www.amazon.com/Free-Banking-Britain-Lawrence-White/dp/0255363753](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0255363753)

to gain a sort of base understanding of matterz.  Not that that helps.